# Unhashable Type "Dict"

Tags: python

I was writing a basic uno-type card game, and wanted to be able to (while making 7 cards for the player) check if the value was already in the player's deck (I used random). I got an unhashable dict error, and some other questions were about the same error, but in different parts of code. Anyways, here's my code.

```
def CardGame():

    nm=8
    clist=["Red","Blue","Green","Yellow"]
    nlist=[]
    for i in range(0,10):
     nlist.append(i)
    pd={}
    deck={"Red":0,"Red":1,"Red":2,"Red":3,"Red":4,"Red":5,"Red":6,"Red":7,"Red":8,"Red":9,"Blue":0,"Blue":1,"Blue":2,"Blue":3,"Blue":4,"Blue":5,"Blue":6,"Blue":7,"Blue":8,"Blue":9,"Green":0,"Green":1,"Green":2,"Green":3,"Green":4,"Green":5,"Green":6,"Green":7,"Green":8,"Green":9,"Yellow":0,"Yellow":1,"Yellow":2,"Yellow":3,"Yellow":4,"Yellow":5,"Yellow":6,"Yellow":7,"Yellow":8,"Yellow":9}
    for i in range(1,nm):
     c=random.choice(clist)
     d=random.choice(nlist)
     if ({c:d}) in deck:
      pd.update({c:d})
      del deck[c:d]
     else:
      nm=nm+1
  print("%s %s"%(c,d))
```

Comment: Not entirely related to your error, but try `print(deck)` right after you create it, and you may be surprised to see how many entries it has.

Comment: Ohhh, I see how the last entry overrided the others; is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Why are you using random to check if a value is in the deck? Seems like you should just loop through all combinations.

Comment: @Rutvik: your dict keys must be unique across all cards.  Your values don't matter so much (you don't really need a dict; a set would do).  You could form your keys as, e.g., "R0", "B8", etc.

Comment: @RutvikMarathe you could use a list of tuples: `[("Red", 0), ("Red", 1)]` or a list of strings: `["Red0", "Red1"]`. In a dictionary, each key can have only one corresponding value. In other words, `deck["Red"]` can only return one value. [More on dictionaries here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Answer (score 1):

With `if ({c:d}) in deck:`, you are checking if the dictionary `{c:d}` is present as a key in the dictionary `deck`.  Dictionaries are unhashable (as mutable data types generally are), and a dictionary key must be hashable, so instead of just telling you "no," it throws the error you saw. A dictionary will never be present as a key in a dictionary.

Also, as noted in the comments, dictionary keys are unique, so the dictionary you made cannot exist as it appears. Consider a different data structure, like a `list` of `tuple`s (e.g. `[('Red', 1), ('Red', 2),...`), or a dictionary with `list` values (e.g. `{'Red':[1, 2, 3,...], 'Blue':[1, 2, 3,...],...}`).

Answer (score 0):

Your specific error comes from how you're trying to check for member ship in the dictionary. The `in` operator checks if a give key exists, but you're passing a one-element dictionary rather than just a key (you get that specific exception because dictionaries are not valid keys since they can't be hashed).

However, as Kevin commented above, you've also got a larger issue where your `deck` dictionary doesn't contain what you want it to contain, since you're reusing the same keys repeatedly. A dictionary can only have a single value for a given key (though the value could be a list or tuple, or some other type that contains additional items).

There are a variety of ways you can fix this issue. A `set` containing 2-tuples would work sort of like how you wanted your `dict` to work. You can `add` and `remove` elements, and efficiently check if a tuple is in the set or not with the `in` operator.

However, looking at what you're actually doing, I think a larger change to your algorithm will be much better. Rather than randomly picking a color and number and then checking if it is still in your `deck`, you should instead just select a random element from the collection directly. Rather than looping to select multiple values, use `random.sample` to select all the values at once. Or, if you're going to be taking more random values from the deck later, `shuffle` it and take a slice.

Here's a version of the code that uses `random.shuffle` on a list of 2-tuples, then slices off 10 of them from the end to become the `pd` list.

```
import itertools
import random

def CardGame():
    nm=8
    clist = ["Red","Blue","Green","Yellow"]
    nlist = list(range(0,10)) # this is easier than looping to append the values
    deck = list(itertools.product(clist, nlist)) # much easier than naming them all
    random.shuffle(deck)
    pd = deck[-10:] # slice 10 items from the end
    del deck[-10:] # and then remove them from the list (fairly efficient at the end)
```